Error docker-compose up --build: failed to calculate checksum of ref : "/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
I've made sure the path is correct multiple times i clean up cache and volume..everything i tried everything
Dockerfile (frontend) root/frontend/Dockerfile
# Stage 1: Build the frontend
FROM node:18 AS build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Serve the frontend
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Dockerfile (Backend) root/backend/Dockerfile
# Stage 1: Build the backend
FROM python:3.9-slim AS build-backend

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

# Stage 2: Final backend image
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-backend /app /app

# Copy nginx configuration files
COPY ../nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ../nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

CMD ["sh", "-c", "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"]

Dockerfile (nginx folder) root/nginx/Dockerfile
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

docker-compose.yml (root) root/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: dollarsandlife
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://username:password@db:5432/dollarsandlife

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - frontend

nginx.conf root/nginx/nginx.conf
# Old code:
# Default configuration for Nginx
# This file was used without any modifications

# New code:
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}


You can never COPY ../... a file from a parent or sibling directory.  In your case, though, the Python application doesn't seem to be using the Nginx configuration at all; can you just delete these lines?
